# Parroting user input

Tags: c#, beginner, console

The below may not look like much, but the ability to call methods in other classes, offloading all the work onto other classes from MainClass, and returning a variable to be passed to the next method is a rather large leap for me at least.

```
using System;

namespace CSharpTutoriel
{
    class Work
    {
        public static string TellMeWhatToSay(out string passTheQuote)
        {
            string whatIsWritten;
            Console.WriteLine("Tell Me What To Say");
            whatIsWritten = Console.ReadLine();
            passTheQuote = whatIsWritten;
            return passTheQuote;
        }
        public static void HelloWorld(string itWillBeSpoken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itWillBeSpoken);
        }
        public static void PressToContinue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string whatToSay;

            Work.TellMeWhatToSay(out whatToSay);
            Work.HelloWorld(whatToSay);
            Work.PressToContinue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _CSharpTutoriel_  has a typo in it, unless you speak French.

Answer (score 6):

#### Redundancy of both `out` parameter and `return`

```
    public static string TellMeWhatToSay(out string passTheQuote)
    {
        string whatIsWritten;
        Console.WriteLine("Tell Me What To Say");
        whatIsWritten = Console.ReadLine();
        passTheQuote = whatIsWritten;
        return passTheQuote;
    }
```

You both write the result to an `out` parameter and return it. A violation the DRY principle, this outputs the same information twice. As the `out` parameter does not feel appropriate for a modern language to me, I will leave only the `return`:

```
    public static string TellMeWhatToSay()
    {
        string whatIsWritten;
        Console.WriteLine("Tell Me What To Say");
        whatIsWritten = Console.ReadLine();
        passTheQuote = whatIsWritten;
        return passTheQuote;
    }
```

Now that we eliminated that redundancy, we can simplify by returning directly:

```
    public static string TellMeWhatToSay()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tell Me What To Say");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

#### Unecessary alias of a built-in `Console.ReadLine`

```
    public static void HelloWorld(string itWillBeSpoken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(itWillBeSpoken);
    }
```

`HelloWorld` is the same as `Console.WriteLine` so there is no need to write it.

Comment: While yes, 'HelloWorld' is completely unnecessary, the point of the exercise was to both offload all work out of MainClass and to pass a variable from one method to another. This is at least the only way I know how to do that.

Comment: @Clol7 `var x = FirstFunction(); var y = SecondFunction(x)` use return values to pass "variables" between functions (really values)

Comment: Once you removed the `out string passTheQuote` declaration, the assignment `passTheQuote = whatIsWritten` became invalid. Remove it, too; and replace `passTheQuote` in the `return` statement with `whatIsWritten`.

Comment: @CiaPan i covered that in the third code sample

Comment: Yes, but the second one remains invalid. It may be worth noting that it is intentionally presented in an intermediate state.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need the `out` attribute here:

```
public static string TellMeWhatToSay(out string passTheQuote)
{
    //...
    return passTheQuote;
}
```

What `out` does, is it requires the parameter to be assigned somewhere in the method a value is returned.  It is only to be used in places such as:

```
public bool trySomething(out parameter)
{
    parameter = someValue;
    return somethingSucceeded;
}
```

Notice how we are supplying two values to the caller in the above method--the return value and the `out` parameter value.

If you don't use the `out` flag, you can change this:

> ```
>    public static string TellMeWhatToSay(out string passTheQuote)
>     {
>         string whatIsWritten;
>         Console.WriteLine("Tell Me What To Say");
>         whatIsWritten = Console.ReadLine();
>         passTheQuote = whatIsWritten;
>         return passTheQuote;
>     }
> ```

to:

```
    public static string TellMeWhatToSay()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tell Me What To Say");
        string whatIsWritten = Console.ReadLine();
        return whatIsWritten;
    }
```

---

Given what you are using this for, the use of `static` members of the `Work` class is alright, although I'd also make the class static.  However, for the most part, you should not work with `static` members like this--you should learn how to instantiate a class and use specific instances.

---

You should allow the user to pass a custom prompt to `TellMeWhatToSay`, instead of just having one prompt.  This will make your input method much more flexible.

Comment: From what I understand of `static` is that it prevents a method from being discarded after use, it didn't seem like a good idea to omit it. But I'll take a look at that.

Comment: No, an instance of a class always has the methods available.  Methods that are static are available outside of instances because they don't carry state.

Comment: @Clol7 _`static` prevents a method from being discarded after use_ :-| where did you overhear this? What should it mean at all? That the method cannot be used anymore?

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm not sure where I heard about it, actually. But what I meant by that was the current state of the method.... now that I think about it that doesn't make sense either.